# Simple Coding Term in Rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

See if you can solve the following rebus.

[image: rebus puzzle]

NOTE: Answer has terms that relate to coding.

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice, that's correct for the first part.

Comment: Nice, but not really a computer puzzle... I think remove that tag.

Comment: Sure @DmitryKamenetsky. I didn't add that... I think someone else did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably

> [CSS Overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

Because

> See | SS | over | flow

Comment: Didn't expect it to be solved so fast! Congrats!